# Why explode by space not work in some space string

Tags: php, arrays, explode

```
2   2019-11-21 21:51:24 0   1
1   2019-11-25 13:32:06 0   1
1   2019-11-25 13:36:31 0   1
1234    2019-11-25 13:38:55 0   1
```

I have output data from website like  above, then  i want to explode that data to array ouput like this, `Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 2019-11-21 [2] => 21:51:24 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 1 [5] => 2019-11-25 [6] => 13:32:06 [7] => 0 [8] => 1 1 [9] => 2019-11-25 [10] => 13:36:31 [11] => 0 [12] => 1 1234 [13] => 2019-11-25 [14] => 13:38:55 [15] => 0 [16] => 1 );`

but when i try to run the output like

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2    2019-11-21
    [1] => 21:51:24 0   1
    [2] => 
    [3] => 1    2019-11-25
    [4] => 13:32:06 0   1
    [5] => 
    [6] => 1    2019-11-25
    [7] => 13:36:31 0   1
    [8] => 
    [9] => 1234 2019-11-25
    [10] => 13:38:55    0   1
)
```

why some space not in explode?

Comment: Replace \n (line break) or multiple space with space and then explode with space

Comment: didnt work, the output `Array ( [0] => 2 2019-11-21 [1] => 21:51:24 0 1 [2] => [3] => 1 2019-11-25 [4] => 13:32:06 0 1 [5] => [6] => 1 2019-11-25 [7] => 13:36:31 0 1 [8] => [9] => 1234 2019-11-25 [10] => 13:38:55 0 1 ) ` still have space not exploded

Comment: Between 2    2019-11-21 two using tab space then try with replace space with \t

Comment: If it looks and smells like CSV treat as CSV.  Your desired array looks harder to process and work with than an array of arrays (array of records).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you need to replace multiple space with single space then perform explode on to  the result

```
$string = '2   2019-11-21 21:51:24 0   1';
$singleSpace = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $string);
$explodeData = explode(" ",$singleSpace);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. It's working.

```
echo "<pre>";

$data = '2   2019-11-21 21:51:24 0   1
1   2019-11-25 13:32:06 0   1
1   2019-11-25 13:36:31 0   1
1234    2019-11-25 13:38:55 0   1';

$newData = explode(" ",str_replace(PHP_EOL," ",$data));
foreach($newData as $k => $v) {
    if($v == null) {
        unset($newData[$k]);
    }
}

print_r(array_values($newData));
```

The output of the above code is:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2019-11-21
    [2] => 21:51:24
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 2019-11-25
    [7] => 13:32:06
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 1
    [10] => 1
    [11] => 2019-11-25
    [12] => 13:36:31
    [13] => 0
    [14] => 1
    [15] => 1234
    [16] => 2019-11-25
    [17] => 13:38:55
    [18] => 0
    [19] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

They are not spaces but tabs. I would expect this to be four tab separated fields.

```
$tsv = <<<"CSV"
2\t2019-11-21 21:51:24\t0\t1
1\t2019-11-25 13:32:06\t0\t1
1\t2019-11-25 13:36:31\t0\t1
1234\t2019-11-25 13:38:55\t0\t1
CSV;

echo $tsv, "\n\n";

foreach(explode("\n", $tsv) as $line) {
    var_dump(explode("\t", $line));
}
```

If you load a file you can provide the separator to `fgetcsv`:

```
$fh = fopen($file, 'rb');
while($line = fgetcsv($fh, 0, "\t")) {
    var_dump($line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = "2   2019-11-21 21:51:24 0   1";
$output = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $data);
$data = explode(" ",$output);
print_r($data);
```